# DST correction when one time is local and one is GMT

Tags: r, lubridate

One data series (nycflights13::flights) is in local time, and one is in GMT (nycflights13::weather). The problem is to merge them in such a way that DST is respected. If we look at January 1, the time difference between America/New_York and GMT should be 5 hours. In June it should be 4 hours. In the following example, I get a 5 hour difference in both January and June -- both `unique(fw1$hour.y)` and `unique(fw6$hour.y)` return 17, but it seems `fw6$hour.y` should be 16. What am I doing wrong?

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(nycflights13)
weather$time_hour <- with_tz(weather$time_hour, 'GMT')
flights$time_hour <- force_tz(flights$time_hour, 'America/New_York')
fw <- left_join(flights, weather, by=c('origin', 'time_hour'))
fw1 <- filter(fw, origin == 'LGA', month.x == 1, day.x == 1, hour.x == 12)
unique(fw1$hour.y)

fw6 <- filter(fw, origin == 'LGA', month.x == 6, day.x == 1, hour.x == 12)
unique(fw6$hour.y)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in version 2.2 (and probably earlier) of `nycflights13`. The file, `weather.R`, generates month, day, and hour from the downloaded source weather file. It then uses these in `ISOdatetime()` to generate the `time_hour` variable, but without specifying a time zone.

This means that while the original weather data is GMT without daylight saving time, the `time_hour` variable created when the package is generated will incorporate daylight saving time as specified in whatever local time zone the package is created. Forcing a time zone when loading the package doesn't alter the fact that daylight saving time has already been incorporated into `time_hour`.

The current development version of `nycflights13` specifies a time zone when generating the time_hour variable so this problem should not occur in the next version of `nycflights13`.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that the 'time_hour' column is supposed to be composed by the year, month, day, hour, columns in each object.  But I get weird results when I look at the month of the 'time_hour' versus the 'month' column.

```
library(lubridate)
library(nycflights13)
weather$time_hour <- with_tz(weather$time_hour, 'GMT')
with(weather, table(month, month(time_hour)))

month    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11   12
   1  2229    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
   2     0 2010    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
   3     0    0 2227    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
   4     0    0    3 2156    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
   5     0    0    0    3 2229    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
   6     0    0    0    0    3 2157    0    0    0    0    0    0
   7     0    0    0    0    0    3 2225    0    0    0    0    0
   8     0    0    0    0    0    0    3 2214    0    0    0    0
   9     0    0    0    0    0    0    0    3 2156    0    0    0
   10    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    3 2209    0    0
   11    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0 2138    0
   12    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0 2159
```

You can see there are a few days during daylight saving time that are not where you would expect based on the value of the 'month' column. So this appears to be an issue with the source data... almost as if a constant 4-hour offset was applied without regard to daylight saving time.

Comment: Your answer suggested looking at how the times are generated in the nycflights13 source code. I've added an explanation of what I think is going on and why I think it's fixed as of the next release of nycflights13.

Comment: @RobertMcDonald great work! You should delete the update from your question and post it as an answer instead. Then you can click the check-mark icon next to your answer so others will know the question is answered.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't sure what was appropriate so I appreciate the advice.

Comment: @RobertMcDonald: You're welcome. You can see [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) for details.